# How do I add space or comma in this output?

Tags: java, spacing

This is a program to sort the user input in ascending and descending order, while I am giving input using spaces I want the output to be displayed in same manner either with spaces or comma.

```
import java.util.*;
class sort4a {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num, i;
    int arr[];
    int temp = 0;
    public void getdata() {
        System.out.print("\nEnter the size of array: ");
        num = input.nextInt();
        arr = new int[num];
        System.out.print("\nEnter the number: ");
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            arr[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
    void putdata() {
        System.out.print("\n\nGiven numbers are: ");
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    void asce() {
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < num; j++) {
                if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n\nAscending order of number are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    void desc() {
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < num; j++) {
                if (arr[i] < arr[j]) {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n\nDescending order of number are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        sort4a ob = new sort4a();
        ob.getdata();
        ob.putdata();
        ob.asce();
        ob.desc();
    }
}
```

My output is this [I want spacing in this output like I am giving space in input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNKln.jpg)

Please suggest correction if my code is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy to do. Just add a `+ ", "` to every `System.out.print()` where you output the array. Also please start using more indentations. It makes it much easier to read for everybody.

```java
    import java.util.*;
    class sort4a {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num, i;
        int arr[];
        int temp = 0;

        public void getdata() {

            System.out.print("\nEnter the size of array: ");
            num = input.nextInt();
            arr = new int[num];
            System.out.print("\nEnter the number: ");

            for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                arr[i] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }

        void putdata() {

            System.out.print("\n\nGiven numbers are: ");

            for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
            }
        }

        void asce() {

            for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < num; j++) {
                    if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                        temp = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.print("\n\nAscending order of number are: ");

            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
            }
        }

        void desc() {
            for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < num; j++) {
                    if (arr[i] < arr[j]) {
                        temp = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.print("\n\nDescending order of number are: ");

            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
            }
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            sort4a ob = new sort4a();
            ob.getdata();
            ob.putdata();
            ob.asce();
            ob.desc();
        }
    }
```